# Multi step form in joomla?

Tags: forms, joomla1.5

I have to make a multistep registration form in joomla.In first step i will only take personal information from user. IF user input the detail correct then only the yser will go to next step.
Please tell me if any plugin or component that provide this kind of functionalty

Thanks in advance
Pramod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which version as the extensions available are different. Assuming you are using 1.5 then you can use Chronoforms. I'm not sure if the 1.6 version can do it, but the 1.5 has multistep form capability and also allows you to enter your own code for processing between forms.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms/1508

Check their website for tutorials on how to make multistep forms.

Comment: In that case you should use the current stable release, V3.2.0 - http://www.chronoengine.com/downloads/chronoforms/chronoforms-j1/component/131-chronoformsv3-2-0.html

Answer (score 1):

I have used this one. Nice userguide included.
http://www.itoris.com/joomla-form-builder-smartformer.html

Comment: FYI requires the commercial version if you need multipage forms.